# Tanaike's Merge PDF script as web app does not return the file ID?

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf

I can successfully run [Tanaike's Merge PDF script](https://tanaikech.github.io/2023/01/10/merging-multiple-pdf-files-as-a-single-pdf-file-using-google-apps-script/) in a google apps script web app. I want to return the file ID of the resultant pdf, but this does not appear possible due to the async function to merge the pdfs. How do I modify my web app code to return the file ID ?

Tanaike suggests a solution [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73086272/2030549), which I have attempted to follow, but it does not work for me.

```
function doGet(e) {
var pdfIds = JSON.parse(e.parameter.pdfIds);
var filename = e.parameter.filename;
return mergePdf(pdfIds,filename);   //<<<<<<<
}

async function mergePdf(pdfIds,filename) {

  const ids = pdfIds;
  const data = ids.map((id) => new Uint8Array(DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getBytes()));

  // Merge PDFs.
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText()); // Load pdf-lib
  const setTimeout = function(f, t) {
    Utilities.sleep(t);
    return f();
  }
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    const pages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [...Array(pdfData.getPageCount())].map((_, i) => i));
    pages.forEach(page => pdfDoc.addPage(page));
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create the merged PDF file.
  const mergedPdf = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, filename));
  const fileId = mergedPdf.getId();  //<<<<<<
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(fileId); //<<<<<<
}
```

Comment: Show what you have tried and add a brief description of your search efforts for helpful content from this site as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: I have attempted to highlight the code I have tried, which is what I would normally do with a synchronous script (code lines with //<<<<<<). I have obviously searched for a solution, but have not found one, or do not understand the concepts presented, hence my question with the code above.

Comment: I have edited my question to include a result of helpful content from this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- I think that in your situation, the method for giving multiple file IDs is required to be known. But, unfortunately, from your question, I cannot know about it. So, in this answer, about the method for requesting Web Apps, I would like to use the following sample curl command.

  ```bash
  $ curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?pdfIds=###fileId1###&pdfIds=###fileId2###&filename=sampleFilename.pdf"
  ```
- When I saw your script, `doGet(e)` is required to be modified. The event object has already been pased as a JSON object. And, in that request, `var pdfIds = JSON.parse(e.parameter.pdfIds);` is required to be modified to `var pdfIds = e.parameters.pdfIds;`.
- And, it seems that in the current stage, when the values returned from the async function are used with `ContentService.createTextOutput`, the values are not supported type. So, when you want to return the file ID, it is required to consider this.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function doGet(e) {
  var pdfIds = e.parameters.pdfIds;
  var filename = e.parameter.filename;
  mergePdf(pdfIds, filename);
  Utilities.sleep(5000); // <--- Please adjust this value.
  var c = CacheService.getScriptCache();
  var fileId = c.get("fileId");
  if (fileId) {
    c.remove("fileId");
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(fileId);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("File ID is not found. Please adjust Utilities.sleep(5000).");
}

async function mergePdf(pdfIds, filename) {
  const ids = pdfIds;
  const data = ids.map((id) => new Uint8Array(DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getBytes()));

  // Merge PDFs.
  const cdnjs = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdf-lib/dist/pdf-lib.min.js";
  eval(UrlFetchApp.fetch(cdnjs).getContentText()); // Load pdf-lib
  const setTimeout = function (f, t) {
    Utilities.sleep(t);
    return f();
  }
  const pdfDoc = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.create();
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const pdfData = await PDFLib.PDFDocument.load(data[i]);
    const pages = await pdfDoc.copyPages(pdfData, [...Array(pdfData.getPageCount())].map((_, i) => i));
    pages.forEach(page => pdfDoc.addPage(page));
  }
  const bytes = await pdfDoc.save();

  // Create the merged PDF file.
  const mergedPdf = DriveApp.createFile(Utilities.newBlob([...new Int8Array(bytes)], MimeType.PDF, filename));
  const fileId = mergedPdf.getId();
  CacheService.getScriptCache().put("fileId", fileId);
}
```

- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- In this case, when you run a curl command like `curl -L "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?pdfIds=###fileId1###&pdfIds=###fileId2###&filename=sampleFilename.pdf"`, the multiple PDF files are merged and a file ID of the created new PDF file is returned.

#### Note:

- In this sample, I used CacheService. But, in this case, a global variable and PropetiesService might be able to be also used.
- **When you modified the Google Apps Script of Web Apps, please modify the deployment as a new version. By this, the modified script is reflected in Web Apps. Please be careful about this.**
- You can see the detail of this in my report "[Redeploying Web Apps without Changing URL of Web Apps for new IDE (Author: me)](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/ebf92d8f427d02d53989d6c3464a9c43)".

Comment: Success !! Thank you very much. I needed to JSON.parse the pdfIds parameter as the file Ids are in a stringified JSON array. Will see if I can reduce the sleep time to help speed things up, and will probably add this as a parameter. (edit - it works with a sleep time of 1000)

Comment: @Metric Rat Thank you for replying and testing it. I think that when the number of PDF files are large, it might be required to set the wait time larger. So, I thought that `will probably add this as a parameter.` will be useful.

Comment: I ran a test with 24 pdf files, totalling @ 4.5mb in size. This still only needed a 1000ms sleep to return the file ID. Instead of a parameter for sleepTime, I have introduced a for loop to run the sleep/fetch file ID routine as many times as needed